# Cannot convert object to primitive value when attempting to run word count on array created from Firebase records

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write a node js program that reads values from a Firebase database and aggregates all the words in a specific field for all the 
records, but I am getting the below errors ..

```
[2019-06-24T14:52:14.083Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value at C:\Users\xxx\Projects\NodeProjects\QuestionAppNode\index.js:52:38

TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Below is my node.js code ..

```
retrieveQuestions();

function retrieveQuestions(){
    userQuestionsFBRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        var fetchedQuestions = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(snapshotChild){
            var itemVal = snapshotChild.val();
            fetchedQuestions.push(itemVal);

        })
        var arrayOfQuestions = [];
        fetchedQuestions.forEach(function(question){
            arrayOfQuestions += question.question
        })
        console.log("Fetched questions are " + JSON.stringify(fetchedQuestions));
        console.log("arrayOfQuestions is " +JSON.stringify(arrayOfQuestions));
        var wordcnt = arrayOfQuestions.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "").split(/\s+/).reduce(function(map, word){
            map[word] = (map[word]||0)+1;
            return map;
        }, Object.create(null));
        console.log("Word count is " + wordcnt)
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}
```

The similar code does work if I run it in Chrome console i.e.

```
var arrayOfQuestions = [{"dateTime":"2019-06-24T14:06:36.983Z","name":"AMA09","question":"Who let the dogs out?"},{"dateTime":"2019-06-24T14:07:11.501Z","name":"AMA09","question":"What is the capital of Senegal?"},{"dateTime":"2019-06-24T14:20:25.222Z","name":"AMA34","question":"Is Free will an illusion?"}];

var newArray = [];

arrayOfQuestions.forEach(question => newArray += question.question);

var wordcnt = newArray.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "").split(/\s+/).reduce(function(map, word){
    map[word] = (map[word]||0)+1;
    return map;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I realise that the approach I am taking to aggregate the words in these records is probably not the correct way to go i.e. adding all the text in the
question field of the fb records is probably a bit stupid and wouldn't work for large datasets so if someone could offer any suggestions on a 
different approach that would be appreciated as well.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on because we can't see the contents of your database.  What *exactly* is in each one of these snapshots?

Comment: Your `wordCnt` variable is an object (a map of word counts) that can't be converted to a string because it lacks a prototype. Try replacing `Object.create(null)` with `{}` in your `reduce` call, or further reducing the `wordCnt` map to a number.

Comment: Thanks t.888. That has worked. Well almost. I get .. {"What":1,"is":2,"free":2,"willDo":1,"we":1,"have":1,"willWhy":1,"the":1,"sky":1,"blue":1} So just need to replace a new line with a space to not combine the first and last words.

Comment: @chucknor, are you looking for a total count of words? What is your desired output?

Comment: Incidentally, `console.log('word count is:', wordCnt)` should work with your original code because you're not coercing `wordCnt` to a string.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be asking more than one question per post, but the approach that I am taking here is not a good one. I couldn't create a single array of all the text in the question records and then aggregating all the words. Is there a more effiecient way to do this?

Comment: I want to get a count of all the unique specific words not a total count of all words i.e. so I could tell how many times the word "consciousness" for example occurred. Eventually I would want some way to not include common words the 'the', 'because' etc. But will have to leave that for another day.

Comment: If your goal is a count of unique words, then I can't think of another way than to iterate each question's words as you're doing. As for words such as "the", you could just delete them from the map, i.e., `delete wordcnt['the']`, but you should probably normalize all your words to lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be this line:

```
console.log("Word count is " + wordcnt)
```

Since `wordcnt` is an object without a prototype, that is, `Object.create(null)`, it has no `toString` method, hence the error *"TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value"*.

**Solution 1 - Use object literal syntax in your reduce expression:**

```
var wordcnt = arrayOfQuestions
  .replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
  .split(/\s+/)
  .reduce(function(map, word){
    map[word] = (map[word]||0)+1;
    return map;
  }, {}); // Object literal instead of Object.create(null)
```

This creates an object with the usual `Object` prototype, which has a `toString` method.

**Solution 2 - Don't concatenate in `console.log` but rather use multiple arguments:**

```
console.log("Word count is", wordcnt) // instead of " + wordcnt)
```

This allows `console.log` to do its normal stringifying of objects.

**Solution 3 - Convert the `wordcnt` map to a json string.**

```
console.log("Word count is " + JSON.stringify(wordcnt))
```

This converts your object to a JSON representation of itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help t.888. I probably need to submit a seperate question for this, but ill ask here anyway. This works fine for this small example but what if my database has thousands of questions? Is pushing all these to one big array and then running mapReduce on this a sensible approach? Also do you know of any libraries that I could use that would filter out common words like 'the' and 'and' etc?

Comment: @chucknor, for common words, search for "stop words list" which should point you to a list of common words that are typically regarded as unimportant/common. As for tracking word count, look for a way to store you map object, perhaps as a JSON string, in a database field. Then when you need to process a comment/question, fetch your map, convert it to an object, i.e., `JSON.parse(mapJson)`, process your question through the map, then write it back to the DB as a string, i.e., `JSON.stringify(wordcnt)`. I don't know anything about firebase or I might be able to recommend something more specific.